# Reading from a text file python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file which contains a matrix of numbers:

```
999 999  10  8
3 4 999 999 999 
6 999 2 7 999
999 6 3 5  6
999 9 1 10 999
10 6 999 2 2 999
```

I'm trying to read each line and store it into an array in Python but
I'm having trouble changing each value into an `int` from a `string`. I tried using the `int()` when parsing each line but I get the error of not being able to pass `list` into the int() argument.

Comment: add sample of your code.

Answer (score 3):

try that:

```
matrix = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in open('myfile.txt')]
```

[edit]
if you don't want the first line just read it before.

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    f.readline()
    matrix = ....
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work good, but I forogot to mention i dont want to be reading the first line of the txt file, any ideas?

Comment: @JJc, please accept whatever answer was useful... you may accept by clicking the outlined grey check mark just below the answer voting arrows

Answer (score 2):

Using [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) to get a `list` of `list`s:

```
>>> with open('myfile.txt') as matrix:
...     [map(int, line.split()) for line in matrix]
...
[[999, 999, 10, 8], [3, 4, 999, 999, 999], [6, 999, 2, 7, 999], [999, 6, 3, 5, 6], [999, 9, 1, 10, 999], [10, 6, 999, 2, 2, 999]]
```

Comment: why `map` inside a list comprehension if `map` does the same thing as `[f(x) for x in iterable]`?

Comment: @JBernardo, `map()` eliminates the inner `for` loop you are using inside your answer

Answer (score 0):

For each line, split on space character, and then convert each token to an int. One way to do this, using list comprehension, is:

```
s = "999 999 10 8"
[int(t) for t in s.split(" ")]
#evaluates to [999, 999, 10, 8]
```

Comment: split splits on whitespace per default

Answer (score -1):

```
nums = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        nums.append([int(n) for n in line.split()])
```

You could write that as one list comprehension, but that could get nasty.

Comment: Why could a list comprehension get nasty?

Comment: @Mike see the other answer. Nested list comprehensions are rarely good form; the one above might be the most concise but it's way too long and dense.

Comment: list comprehensions are fast and less verbose. CPython's gc closes the file if opened inside a comprehension.